# Wordpress Multisite with own domain, Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: wordpress, apache, webmin

I am using CentOS 7.6, Webmin 1.930, Virtualmin 6.07 Pro. and Wordpress Multisite (5.2.3) and have it all working but can't work out how to setup a domain for each Multisite.

I think I need to manually edit the Apache config files.  Currently, I set up the Multisites to be in sub-directories but can set them up as sub-domains if needed (I guess if I use sub-domains I map the domains for each site to the sub-domain).

Comment: I empathize with your confusion. I do not know WP Multisites at all. I do use Virtualmin. I found this page which needs sifting through https://www.virtualmin.com/node/35648, and another here https://virtualmin.com/node/25349. I searched Google using wordpress multisite virtualmin. If you find the answer, could you please share it with us? Cheers!!